# Sending BLOBs in a JSON service,... how?

Tags: json, servlets, blob, jsonp

I have a webservice (ie. servlet) implemented in Java. It gets some data from a MySQL table, with one column being of type BLOB (an image), and some other columns are just plain text.
Normally I would store the file outside the database with a pointer to it in the database, but due to circumstance I now have to use this BLOB column...

What is the proper way to send this? How to encode the image in a JSONObject, and how to parse (and RENDER!) it on the otherside ?

I want to use JSONP, to avoid having to proxy it through the consumer's webserver.

So that the consumer can just put in a  tag pointing to the webservice, calling a callback.

Any thoughts how to handle images in this situation? Also thoughts on performance etc. are interesting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of java-side base64_encode to make sure BLOB fits into text-only json, then javascript-side to base64_decode and/or [inline images](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/inline-images/) for rendering.

Comment: Okay, I will try this. As far as performance goes: it seems that it saves on http requests, but potentially misses paralellization opportunities, correct? What would be faster in terms on page loading on the consumer-side?

Comment: This depends on how you organize your queries, you can deliver blobs in parallel by sending special requests and including them in the resulting page as, say, `<img src="[your-request-url]" />`. at a cost of increased number of http requests, of course.